# PHP post variables titles

Tags: php, html

I am wondering how I can extract the title variable from my forms posted fields array.

I know $_POST['name'] is the field name but can I do something like $_POST[title] to get the title?

I ask because I have a dynamic form with variable lengths. The dynamics is group_one contains 5 fields, group_two contains 12 fields, group_three contains 2 fields for example.

I am hoping to loop through these groups and post the title of the form field to a column in a DB and its value. Any help appreciated with understanding if I can use the 'title' variable in the form field element.

```
<input type="radio" name="txtGroupOne[]" id="txtDogAtPremisesYes" value="Yes" title="Dog at premises" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="txtGroupOne[]" id="txtDogAtPremisesNo" value="No" title="Dog at premises" />No                               
<input type="text" name="txtGroupOne[]" id="txtNextOfKinName" title="Next of kin name" />                               
<input type="text" name="txtGroupOne[]" id="txtNextOfKinContact" title="Next of kin contact" />
```

Comment: `but can I do something like` - it takes a minute to check, and ~5 minutes to ask a question and wait for the answers. Why have you chosen the latter?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is asking. Sample form HTML perhaps?

Comment: You should start by reading this page if you haven't yet. It will give you a better understanding of how to handle submitted POST variables:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: I do (mostly) understand the post method. I just wasn't sure if 'title' was available to use as I have never needed it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @zerkms - Sorry, the first line shouldnt be a question. The problem is more of a: 'yes you can use the title variable in a post and this should help you' or 'no it cant be done' which in that case I will work out another way of doing it. Looks like its a no without Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add hidden field to each of fields that need titles to be sent to server besides their values.

```
<input type="radio" name="txtGroupOne[]" id="txtDogAtPremisesYes" value="Yes" />
<input type="hidden" name="txtGroupOneTitles[]" value="Dog at premises" >

<input type="radio" name="txtGroupOne[]" id="txtDogAtPremisesNo" value="No" />
<input type="hidden" name="txtGroupOneTitles[]" value="Dog at premises" >

<input type="text" name="txtGroupOne[]" id="txtNextOfKinName" />
<input type="hidden" name="txtGroupOneTitles[]" value="Next of kin name" >

<input type="text" name="txtGroupOne[]" id="txtNextOfKinContact" />
<input type="hidden" name="txtGroupOneTitles[]" value="Next of kin contact" >
```

Comment: Looks like this is the way to go. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, only the `name="x"` attribute is sent by default in an HTML Form. `title="x"` is not sent. You can technically get around it with some crazy Javascript and an Ajax POST, but I would avoid that if I were you.

What do you want the title sent to your server side for? There surely probably a better alternative to achieve your goal.

Comment: I am performing the post using AJAX so maybe I will add the title to the serialized string. Thanks

Comment: @KerePuki Alright, if you're already submitting the form using ajax with serialized string it shouldn't be too much extra work. IE. You can grab the `title` with `getAttribute('title')` in Javascript, or if you're using jQuery already you can just use `attr('title')` then put it in your string, or into a Javascript object or array if possible before it gets serialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $form_var){
    // Compile your code here, etc.
}
```

Anything that does not have a "name" attribute in your form will not be part of the $_POST array.

ie,

```
<input type='text' id='bar'>
<input type='text' name='foo' id='foo'>
```

Only $_POST['foo'] would exist.

Misread the question slightly, but you could also prepend your input names to include the "group title" upon generation.

```
<input type='text' name='title1_foo' id='title1_foo'>
```

Then you can manipulate the information you want from the $_POST loop.